# Usin multiple Yii applications

Tags: php, css, yii, nginx, path

I have following directory structure

- root/
- root/protected
- root/framework
- root/backend
- root/backend/protected

Well, first Yii application is located directly inside root at the same level with framework folder. Second Yii application located inside `backend` folder. They both use same framework folder which located in `root`.

I'm using path style url's in both applications. like `mydomain.com/controller/action`.

## Problem is ..

But when I try to open
`mydomain.com/backend/` yii tries to pass `backend` as controller name to `mydomain.com/index.php` and gives me 404. But in fact it's subdirectory of separate application

I tried to resolve this problem: Changed the content of `root/index.php` to the following code:

```
<?php
if (strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 'backend') !== false) {
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/backend/index.php';
} else {

// change the following paths if necessary
    $yii = dirname(__FILE__) . '/framework/yii.php';
    $config = dirname(__FILE__) . '/protected/config/main.php';

// remove the following lines when in production mode
    defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
    defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL', 3);

    require_once($yii);
    Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();

}
```

It worked, but all media, css files paths messed up: for ex. css located inside `backend/css` tries to open mydomain.com/img.jpg instead of `mydomain.com/backend/img.jpg`.

In other words, what I tried is not right solution. My webserver is NGINX and configuration looks like that:

```
server {
    set $host_path "/var/www/mydomain";

    server_name mydomain.com;
    root $host_path;
    set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$yii_bootstrap?$args;
    }

    location /backend/ {
        index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$yii_bootstrap?$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(protected|framework|themes/\w+/views) {
        deny  all;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        #let yii catch the calls to unexising PHP files
        set $fsn /$yii_bootstrap;
        if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
            set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
        }
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
      }


    # prevent nginx from serving dotfiles (.htaccess, .svn, .git, etc.)
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use and treat it as a Yii module instead? You are capable to create multiple sub apps since Yii facilitate you to make it, then you can access it look like www.domain.com/backend/controller/action

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do any kind of changes on core. Better try with routing.

something like this -

'/backend/controller/action' => '/controller/action/' in main.php configuration.

Hope this helps...

Comment: root/backend is seperate Yii application. I don't want any dependency with application which located on root/. Basically, now when I open mydomain.com/backend it tries to pass `backend` as controller name to mydomain.com/index.php/ So your answer doesn't make any sense

Comment: Yes I know, but I don't want to access /backend through root applications root rules, it will be very limited